# How do I import a class to extend with ES6 and Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm new to webpack and am trying to require or import a class to extend in another file, and continually end up with the class being undefined. Here's the file setup.

app.js

`require('./stuff.js');`

stuff.js

`require('./Subclass.js');`

Subclass.js

```
require('./Superclass.js');

class Subclass extends Superclass {
}
```

Superclass.js

```
class Superclass {
}
```

And compiling with webpack via `webpack app.js bundle.js`

With this I end up with `Superclass is not defined` when including bundle.js in the browser.

I have also tried using import with exports, doing

Subclass.js

```
import Superclass from './Superclass';

// I have also tried
// import {Superclass} from './Superclass';

class Subclass extends Superclass {
}
```

Superclass.js

```
export default class Superclass {
}
```

But that results in Superclass being undefined when trying to extend, causing the error `Super expression must either be null or a function, not object`

This is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your initial stab at it was wrong because:

1. You aren't importing `Superclass` correctly
2. You aren't exporting `Subclass` or `Superclass`

Your second attempt is closer as your importing `Superclass` correctly but again you fail export `Subclass` - to summarise, this should fix your code

**Subclass.js**

```
import Superclass from './Superclass';

export default class Subclass extends Superclass {
   ...
}
```

**Superclass.js**

```
export default class Superclass {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but adding the export to the Subclass in addition to the Superclass does not change the result of Superclass not being defined.

Comment: @Zurahn are you using the code exactly as above? If you are, what error are you seeing? As this should work...

Comment: It appears I was editing a file I had moved to different location, so my changes weren't being reflected. *headdesk* Thank you!